# What is this sign? "(|>) -(~)"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have compared this with a structure, what exactly is this?
I have come across a [Kickstarter iOS application](https://github.com/kickstarter/ios-oss) that looks like this, what exactly are these characters?

```
override func bindStyles() {
 _ = self |> loginControllerStyle

 _ = self.loginButton |> loginButtonStyle

 _ = self.forgotPasswordButton |> forgotPasswordButtonStyle

 _ = self.emailTextField |> emailFieldStyle
  |> UITextField.lens.returnKeyType .~ .next

 _ = self.passwordTextField |> passwordFieldStyle
  |> UITextField.lens.returnKeyType .~ .go

 _ = self.formDividerView |> separatorStyle

 _ = self.formBackgroundView |> cardStyle()

 _ = self.onePasswordButton |> onePasswordButtonStyle

 _ = self.rootStackView |> loginRootStackViewStyle
}
```

Comment: It looks like these are from the Argo framework... https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo a dependency of the Kickstarter framework you  linked.

Comment: you need to find the code where the operator is overloaded to check out what those operators mean.

Comment: Somebody decided to implement a new programming language inside Swift.

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you!

Comment: @Fogmeister, it's not Argo, it's [Prelude](https://github.com/robrix/Prelude). `|>` is apply operator. You can interpret `x |> f` as `f(x)`.

Comment: @user28434 Post an answer?